# How does a TCP/IP socket report that the foreign host has closed the connection?

Tags: tcp

Consider me a newbie in terms of socket programming.

Suppose I use telnet to connect to a webserver:

```
# telnet localhost 80
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /
(blah blah blah)
connection closed by foreign host.
```

My question regards writing an application to do the same thing.  Basically, I write Perl.  But I don't think this is a Perl specific question.

In Perl, I create a socket using IO::Socket::INET, which extends IO::Handle.  Essentially, a socket has the same properties as a file handle, which I understand is the definition of a "socket" in unix- indistinguishable from a file handle.

My app is intended to mimick the telnet functionality described above.  I open the socket and write the string "GET /\n\n", and get exactly the same results- except for the "connection closed by foreign host".  In fact, all of the socket properties appear unchanged.

My question is: In Perl or otherwise, how can I query the socket properties to determine the result reported via telnet.  That is, how can I determine that the foreign host has closed the connection?

Comment: Typically, the result of a `select` or `read` will tell you what's going on with the socket, including this condition.

Comment: As @LightnessRacesinOrbit pointed out, you try to read and catch the exception or errno. In my experience, I always get SIGPIPE when the remote closes the socket while i try to read from it.

Comment: @alvits No you don't. That only happens when *writing,* or when reading if you had previously written while the peer had already closed, or if the peer closed abortively for some other reason. Normally you will get an unambiguous end-of-stream indication from the stream. What that is exactly depends on what API you're using, but it doesn't include SIGPIPE.

Comment: @EJP you are absolutely correct. I am using `recv()` and I do get the SIGPIPE on `send()` when the client is killed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak for Perl, but in the C Sockets API:

- `read()` and `recv()` return zero when the peer has closed the connection and you have read all the data he has previously sent.
- `send()` and `write()` will eventually return -1 with `errno` = `ECONNRESET` if you keep writing to a connection that has already been closed by the peer.

There is no 'state' of a TCP socket that you can enquire on independently of sending or receiving that will give you this information.

Comment: If the status can be gained using 'select' - that function is implemented in Perl and seems like the best answer.

Comment: +1 This is almost how I write socket programs. But I'll be honest, little tips like this has taught me a lot.

Comment: @SunnyJim Only the 'readable', 'writable', and 'error' states can be determined via `select()`. End of stream, i.e. the usual peer disconnection case, cannot.

Comment: So I've discovered :)

Comment: @EJP To clarify, two conditions establish a connection-closed-by-peer:  select() indicates the fd is ready for reading and read() returns 0.  Is that right?

Comment: select() indicates readability. It is the zero return from recv() that unambiguously indicates end of stream.